# Best way to loop through a string in another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

So I needed a count and some more info on all of the objects I have in an S3 bucket.

```
var allObjItems = [];

s3.listObjects({Bucket: 'myBucket'}, function(err, data) {
    var turnObjInString = JSON.stringify(allObjItems);

    fs.writeFile("test", turnObjInString, function(err) {
}
```

So here, I grab all the objects in the S3 bucket, stringify them and write them to a file.

I need to iterate over the objects and get the key. So an object looks like :

```
 Key: 'e13_28_3_m204as37h7a33buu26qkwy2vsxk05p_q173.png',
    LastModified: Thu Apr 14 2016 19:17:24 GMT+0100 (BST),
    ETag: '"SomethingRandomStringHere"',
    Size: 760456,
    StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
    Owner: 
     { DisplayName: 'servers',
       ID: 'someRandomID' } },
```

What's the best way, since i've stringified them to be able to write them to a file to iterate over them and grab all the keys? Keeping in mind the file is that large i've wrote too I can't open it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this simply with `Object.keys`, which takes an Object and returns an array containing the objects keys::

```
var map = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3};
var keys = Object.keys(map);
console.log(keys); // [a, b, c]
```

Depending on your needs, you could simply replace your current `turnObjInString` String with the array of keys to write.

Comment: Yup, just realised just as I posted the question I can do the sorting before I write to a file. The reason I stringify it is because Node doesn't allow you to write to files as objects so I was struggling on how i'd iterate over the string in the file and grab the info I need. But I can do the sorting out beforehand :) thanks man! i'll accept as correct answer when I can :)